# Command After Semicolon Not Executed in Crontab?

Tags: linux, crontab, sh

Here is my crontab:

```
42 17 * * 1-5 /bin/pkill -f 'MyExecutable.exe' ;  touch /tmp/here.log
```

And according to `/var/log/cron` it did run:

```
May 22 17:42:01 server1 CROND[326732]: (myuser) CMD (/bin/pkill -f 'MyExecutable.exe' ;  touch /tmp/here.log)
```

And the process of `MyExecutable.exe` did die. However, `here.log` wasn't created in `/tmp`.

If I manually run it under myuser:

```
touch /tmp/here.log
```

the file is created successfully (hence, not permission issue for sure). I even tried to move `touch` into a separate cronjob in crontab, and it worked.

Why doesn't `touch` after the semicolon run?

Comment: Is it possible that `touch` isn't in the default crontab path (`/usr/bin`)?

Comment: Nah, it is there.  I even tried to move touch into a separate cronjob in crontab, and it worked.

Comment: What happens if you enclose the two commands in parenthesis ?

Comment: like 42 17 * * 1-5 (/bin/pkill -f 'MyExecutable.exe' ;  touch /tmp/here.log)?

Comment: Yes, try it like that.

Answer (score 3):

This can be replicated by

```
sh -c 'pkill -f "MyExecutable.exe" ; touch /tmp/here.log'
```

Cron runs your command by passing it to a shell (`sh` or other), so effectively it's very similar to the above line. Regardless of whether any `MyExecutable.exe` runs or not, `pkill -f` matches (also) the shell and kills it before it runs `touch`. This is because

> The pattern is normally only matched against the process name. When `-f` is set, the full command line is used.

<sup>(source: [`man 1 pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill))</sup>

Possible solutions:

1. If you don't need `-f`, just drop it:

   ```
   42 17 * * 1-5 /bin/pkill 'MyExecutable.exe' ;  touch /tmp/here.log
   ```
2. If you do need `-f`, run `touch` before `pkill`:

   ```
   42 17 * * 1-5 touch /tmp/here.log ; /bin/pkill -f 'MyExecutable.exe'
   ```

Answer (score 2):

This question relates with this one:

[Running two commands sequentially in a cron job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639434/running-two-commands-sequentially-in-a-cron-job?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

You should separate the two commands with &&, instead of ;

Comment: I believe that && is used if the user really wants to run the second command after the first one is success.  However, a user might want to run the 2nd command regardless whether the first command is success.